# Is "assess" appropriate here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language

(One is in a coma)

Doctor: Unfortunately nothing gives us reason to believe that his condition will improve, but cases like this are never easy to **assess** and therefore we can't say anything with certainty.

I have a hard time figuring out *assess* and when to use it. Would it seem natural in the above context? Or are there better options?

Comment: Yes, it seems quite natural here. The doctor finds it difficult to form an opinion from the patient's symptoms.